# How to add new numbers in Twilio using c# for verifying and Sending SMS

Tags: c#, sms, twilio

Am new to twilio.
i cant send sms until i verify user phone number in twilio account .
please let me know is there any way for verify the number in twilio using c#.
I want send sms in bulk so please let me know how to verify using c#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a developer evangelist for Twilio, here to help!

I am guessing that you currently have a trial account. You have to verify numbers in order to send SMS to them during your trial period.

In order to send to any number without verification, you just need to upgrade your account and add a payment method. Once you have done that you will be able to send all the SMS messages you want!

Let me know if this helps, or if I can help any further.

Comment: That's awesome! Would you mind marking the answer as correct so that others can see that? Thanks!